# Why isn't vstest.executionengine.x86.exe closing on Team Build servers?

Tags: tfs, build

We've been running into the same problem (see:  [vstest.executionengine.x86.exe not closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497168/vstest-executionengine-x86-exe-not-closing)). Unfortunately since the changes (suggested in that area) only work on the local machine and do not (appear) to persist anywhere in the solution (and hence can't be checked into source control) the build server continues to keep vstest.executionengine.x86.exe open. I should also note that preemptively killing instances of the process as a post build step on the build server can only be safely done if there's 1 Build Agent per server.

There's a real lack of documentation regarding how to solve these types of issues on Team Build servers!!!

I eventually discovered the following article:

http://gordonbeeming.azurewebsites.net/2013/01/24/vstest-executionengine-x86-exe-not-closing/

It suggested creating a blank test runner file and associating that with the solution. Unfortunately MS fell short here too as the change is (yet again) only applicable to the local box running Visual Studio, not the Team Build server. Eventually I discovered a setting in the Build Definition where a blank test runner file could be associated with the Build Def and like magic my solution would build on the build server and vstest.executionengine.x86.exe closed when the build completed. Came back this morning ready to convert the rest of our build definitions but lo and behold this solution DOES NOT consistently work. Besides what solutions are built and workspaces are defined the Build Definitions ARE IDENTICAL. I'm completely perplexed as to why adding the blank test runner file fixed the problem in one case but not in others...

Has anyone else encountered this on Team Build servers and if so what was your solution?

Comment: Why do you not have Visual Studio installed on your build server? Build servers should reflect development machines....

Comment: Visual Studio is installed on the build machines, however the Build Controllers/Agents, do not handle builds in the same exact fashion as Visual Studio.  Using the same solutions as outlined in other posts (see above) does not work when kicking the builds off via Team Build.

Comment: If you are using TFS 2013 and the *12.xaml template it should be handles in 'almost' the same way. Previous versions o the template did do it divergently.. You would need to post error messaged and a lot more information before I could help you figure this out...